# Is it possible to pass parameters to GDB as the command line?

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I am running someone's code and the code crashes on a specific dataset, but the crash message as-is is not informative. I cannot call GDB and then wait (for GDB) to pass `r` to it (things are running on a cluster). Is there a way to pass *r* to GDB in the runtime by default, something like the following?

```
 gdb r ./run
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load your program in GDB, like:

```
$ gdb your_program_name
```

and then attach to process which you want to debug

```
attach pid
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a commands file. Write all the commands you want to execute sequentially in the file. And use that file to pass the command to GDB with input redirection:

```
echo "r" > cmds
gdb r --args ./run -arg1 -arg2 -arg3 < cmds
```

Comment: The issue, which is why I posted this question, is that $gdb r ./run $ doesn't work. I just edit the question to make it simpler.

Comment: @user3639557: so you see crash well before you land into gdb commad prompt?